# Python Slicing NumPy Array according to feature_importances_

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, scikit-learn

I have a set of features as a `NumPy` array.

`RandomForestRegressor` in `Scikit-Learn` returns `feature_importances_`, in which there are importance values of all features.

I need to slice the `NumPy` array so that only most important 50 features left and other columns are removed.

How can I do that easily?

Comment: Could you please provide some code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, what you are looking for is [argsort](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argsort.html). It will return the indices into a sorted array in increasing order. As an example:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor as RFR

# Create a random number generator so this example is repeatable
rs = np.random.RandomState(seed=1234)

# create 100 fake input variables with 10 features each
X = rs.rand(100, 10)
# create 100 fake response variables
Y = rs.rand(100)

rfr = RFR(random_state=rs)
rfr.fit(X, Y)

fi = rfr.feature_importances_
# argsort the feature importances and reverse to get order of decreasing importance
indices = argsort(fi)[::-1]
```

`indices` now contains the indices of the input variables in order of decreasing feature importance.

```
In: print indices
[7 6 3 4 5 0 1 9 2 8]
In: print fi[indices]
[ 0.22636046  0.19925157  0.17233547  0.09245424  0.08287206  0.0800437
  0.07174068  0.05554476  0.01044851  0.00894855]
```

Keep the first `n` most import features in the input variable by slicing appropriately:

```
X[:, indices[:n]] # n most important features
```